# Convert string with unknown format (any format) to date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have data that contains a date string.

Normally it would be in a 'Jan. 3, 1966' type format, but because of international differences, it may not always be exactly that.

I need to read the data in and convert it into a standard date string ('YYYY-MM-DD').

Basically this is what I have so far:

```
var dataString = 'Jan. 3, 1966'  
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()  
dateFormatter.dateFormat = # I DON'T KNOW THE EXACT INPUT FORMAT !
let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dataString)
```

Comment: please add some code snippets with examples of your problem and the solution that you may have tried.

Comment: What are the other possible values of date format that you want to handle in your code?

Comment: I don't know all the possible variations, but it could be things like 'January 3, 1966'  or 'Jan 3, 1966'  or '3 Jan 1966'.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2 or later**

You can use NSDataDetector as follow:

```
extension String {
    var nsString: NSString { self as NSString }
    var length: Int { nsString.length }
    var nsRange: NSRange { .init(location: 0, length: length) }
    var detectDates: [Date]? {
        try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue)
                .matches(in: self, range: nsRange)
            .compactMap(\.date)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == String {
    var dates: [Date] { compactMap(\.detectDates).flatMap{$0}
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
let dateStrings = ["January 3, 1966","Jan 3, 1966", "3 Jan 1966"]
for dateString in dateStrings {
    if let dateDetected = dateString.detectDates?.first {
        print(dateDetected)
        // 1966-01-03 14:00:00 +0000
        // 1966-01-03 14:00:00 +0000
        // 1966-01-03 14:00:00 +0000
    }
}


let dateStrings = ["January 3, 1966","Jan 3, 1966", "3 Jan 1966"]

for date in dateStrings.dates {
    print(date)
    // 1966-01-03 14:00:00 +0000
    // 1966-01-03 14:00:00 +0000
    // 1966-01-03 14:00:00 +0000
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't the dateFormat "LLL. dd, yyyy" linked to a date formatted like "Jan. 3, 1966".  Would this work with strings in other formats?

Comment: I think your best bet would be probably NSDataDetector

Comment: Thank you! Your solution was great.

Comment: @LeoDabus + 1000 !! even dates like 11/11/1959 work.

Comment: Godlike +1! And a lifesaver!

Comment: This is MAGIC! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in swift 4, xcode 9

```
extension String {
        var detectDate: Date? {
            let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue)
            let matches = detector?.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.utf16.count))
            return matches?.first?.date
        }
    }
```

Test:

`print("2018-11-04T23:59:00+00:00".detectDate ?? "")`  // 2018-11-04 10:00:00 +0000

`print("2018/11/4".detectDate ?? "")` // 2018-11-04 10:00:00 +0000

Comment: This caused a bug for example, 4/8/2020 sometimes converted to 4 August and another time was converted to 8 Apr , as it's unknown whicj is month and which is the day