# Is it safe to use try! NSDataDetector()

Tags: swift, nsdatadetector

> Return Value Returns the newly initialized data detector. If an error
>   was encountered returns nil, and error contains the error.

That is all the apple docs say about `NSDataDetector` and it's `init`.

Is it only wrapped in a `do try catch` because you might feed it a set of `NSTextCheckingType` that will fail the `init` or does it have some dependencies that might make it fail?

**Or to put it another way:**

If an init works once, will it always work and can I then use `try!`

This works:

```
guard let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Date.rawValue) else {
    return
}
```

So will this always work:

```
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Date.rawValue)
```

Not having to deal with optionals would be great in some cases.
Of course the class might one day change and then it might fail. So this question is just about `NSDataDetector` as it exists today.

---

**Update :**

`NSDataDetector` and all `NSTextCheckingType`'s are available from iOS 4. This makes me think that once an init works, it will always work.

next thing I will check:

Are all init's, or all functions, that accept an OptionSetType fallible?

Comment: why not using an optional chaining?

Comment: @Sega-Zero I am curious about `NSDataDetector` itself. Implementing it as-is is no problem.

Comment: @RMenke http://stackoverflow.com/a/32595941/2303865