# Converting String to NSDate from additional value

Tags: objective-c, string, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert String to NSDate format.

```
strDate = "22nd Jan 2016"
```

Which format can be used for converting this string to NSDate format.

Comment: You want  format of the date formatter to be used?

Comment: @Arun Yes. Through that format I should be able to get NSDate. Currently I'm getting null for all my formats

Comment: @AnkitaShah you will probably need to take the 'nd' out of your string. but it could  be also st, rd or th depending on your date. `"dd'nd' LLL yyyy"` would work only for that date

Comment: @LeoDabus Here it will contain all the dates from 1 to 31, which will have their particular annotation. So no other option then maintaining manually?

Comment: you will have to use data detector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32595941/2303865

Comment: `let strDate = "22nd Jan 2016";

if let date = strDate.detectDate {
    print(date)
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus This solved my problem. Thank you so much

Comment: @AnkitaShah you are welcome I will update that answer. You can also have multiple dates in the same string it will return an array of dates