# SwiftDate Accepts Invalid Dates

Tags: swift, macos, date

I'm using `SwiftDate` (from `malcommac.github`) to validate string dates, but I find that it accepts as valid the 31st of ANY month (Feb, Nov, whatever). The 32nd of any month fails on a `SwiftDate.DateError.FailedToParse`.

The following is taken from an example on the `SwiftDate` GitHub page. The printed result is `01 dic 1999, 23:30:00 CET`.

```
let regionRome = Region(tz: TimeZoneName.europeRome, cal: CalendarName.gregorian, loc: LocaleName.italian)
// Parse a string which a custom format
let date1 = try! DateInRegion(string: "1999-11-31 23:30:00", format: .custom("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), fromRegion: regionRome)
print(date1)
```

Am I overlooking something? I assume this result isn't intended.

Comment: When parsed, does it return the 31 of that month, or the _last_ day of the month? What's the output of `date1`? In some libs, specifying the 31st automatically returns the last day of the month.

Comment: This question should be asked of the developer through the Issues section of the project website.

Comment: It returns the 31st. The output of date1 is Dec 1.

Comment: The GitHub SwiftDate page suggests "If you need help, use Stack Overflow. (Tag ‘swiftdate’)".

Comment: @JGCR try `let dateStr = "1999-11-31 23:30:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)   // "Dec 1, 1999, 11:30 PM"` same result

Comment: @Leo Dabus So, does this mean that we can't use SwiftDate OR DateFormatter for date validation?

Comment: @JGCR yes you can you just need to set isLenient to false  `dateFormatter.isLenient = false`

Comment: Example for isLenient: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39730502/1187415.

Comment: @Leo Dabus Yes, 'isLenient' solves the problem when using dateFormatter. I can't see that there is anything similar in SwiftDate. I'll keep sniffing around.