# Convert datestring to Swift 3 NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I having a date string:

> Wed Mar 25 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

I want to convert this string to the `Date` object in Swift 3.

I have referred to [Link1](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/), [Link 2](https://jeffkayser.com/projects/date-format-string-composer/index.html) and [Link 3](http://nsdateformatter.com/) for generating the format for this date string but could not get the correct format.

Comment: As I said, the concern is not with the code, the concern is I am unable to get the format for the mentioned date string.

Comment: This one is interesting. The format `"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)"` should work. That format will format a `Date` object into the same format shown in the question and it will properly parse a string in the format shown in the question but only if it is some other timezone. `DateFormatter` doesn't seem to like the `IST` timezone. I had no trouble parsing the string `"Wed Mar 25 2017 05:30:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)"` using the format I mentioned.

Comment: There are definitely issues with the `IST` timezone. Please see [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dateformatter+ist). Since it's ambiguous, `DateFormatter` can't handle it when parsing.

Comment: `IST` is ambiguous as it stands for both `Irish Standard Time` and `Indian Standard Time`

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you have string which contains timezone names like `IST` or `GMT` differences, then you can use `NSDateDetector` as explained in [this SO post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595941/5546312):

```
extension String {
  var nsString: NSString { return self as NSString }
  var length: Int { return nsString.length }
  var nsRange: NSRange { return NSRange(location: 0, length: length) }
  var detectDates: [Date]? {
    return try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue)
        .matches(in: self, range: nsRange)
        .flatMap{$0.date}
  }
}

//your example here
let dateString = "Wed Mar 25 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"
if let dateDetected = dateString.detectDates?.first {
    let date = dateDetected//Mar 25, 2017, 5:30 AM
    print(dateDetected)//2017-03-25 00:00:00 +0000 - this is GMT time
}
```

> **Mar 25, 2017, 5:30 AM** //date converted to local time zone
>   2017-03-25 00:00:00 +0000 //printed value of GMT time

---

**2)** Or if you some how able to remove `GMT` and `IST` reference from your string then try this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "Wed Mar 25 2017 05:30:00 +0530")!
print(date)
```

It will give you

> **Mar 25, 2017, 5:30 AM** //date converted to local time zone
>   2017-03-25 00:00:00 +0000 //printed value of GMT time

Answer (score -1):

```
var dateString = "Wed, 25 Mar 2017 05:30:00 +0000"
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
var dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print(dateFromString)
```

Comment: "Wed, 25 Mar 2017 05:30:00 +0000" it is not the same string that has been asked by the OP

Comment: ok then just change dateformatter  to this : dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

Comment: That's still not at all the same. Details matter.