# Date formatting for next available date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

I'm currently downloading fixture lists for a sports app from a third party website that runs the league, so the data I have to work with is restricted.

I'm trying to implement a feature that displays the next upcoming fixture. 
My problem is the dates being retrieved look like this:

"Sat 9th Sep 17" and "Sat 24th Mar 18" for example.

I've tried numerous date formats in the DateFormatter that I know of and can't find anything that uses this specific format.

If I try to use the Date from string method in the date formatter with one of the above strings I get a nil value.

I have an array of fixtures, each with their own dates. I need to compare each of these to the current date to figure out which is next in line.

My temporary fix for this was just to loop through the fixtures and as soon as one did not have a result to display that as the next fixture. Obviously this doesn't work when a game may not have been played for whatever reason.

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Show what you have tried and the issues you have encountered.

Comment: You can use NSDataDetector. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595651/convert-string-with-unknown-format-any-format-to-date/32595941#32595941

Comment: If you don't want to use NSDataDetector you would need to use 3 different dateFormat (st, nd and th) when trying to parse your date string "EEE d'st' MMM yy", `"EEE d'nd' MMM yy"` or "EEE d'th' MMM yy"

Comment: I used the NSDateDetector and worked great, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would just need to convert the current date to the same format as the date you get from your third party website (or the opposite) so you can compare them easily:

```
    let currentDate = Date()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EE MMM"
    let firstPartStringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy"
    let lastPartStringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)

    let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: currentDate)

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal

    guard let ordinalDay = formatter.string(for: day) else {
        return
    }

    let finalDateString = firstPartStringDate + " \(ordinalDay) " + lastPartStringDate

    print(finalDateString)
```

And for today's current date you would get the exactly same format as the one you get from the third-party website :

```
Sun Sep 17th 17
```

**UPDATE:** Here is how you could convert the `String` you get from the third-party website to a `Date`, and then compare it with the current date. This solves the problem of having the st, nd, rd and th inside the `String` at first.

```
// This is the string you get from the website    

    var webDateString = "Sat 9th Sep 17"

// First, remove the st, nd, rd or th if it exists :

    if let stSubrange = webDateString.range(of:"st") {
        webDateString.removeSubrange(stSubrange)
    } else if let ndSubrange = webDateString.range(of:"nd") {
        webDateString.removeSubrange(ndSubrange)
    } else if let rdSubrange = webDateString.range(of:"rd") {
        webDateString.removeSubrange(rdSubrange)
    }  else if let thSubrange = webDateString.range(of:"th") {
        webDateString.removeSubrange(thSubrange)
    }

// Now convert the string to a date :   

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EE MMM dd yy"
    guard let formattedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: finalDateString) else {
        return
     }

// You can now compare formattedDate and the current date easily like so :

    let currentDate = Date()

    if formattedDate < currentDate {

        // Do something interesting here :)

    } else {

        // Do something else!
    }
```

Comment: No need to create a new NSNumber object, you can use string(for:) instead of string(from:) `formatter.string(for: day)`. Btw the OP wants to get a date not a string

Comment: This would just be an extra step because we need to have the day as a value here and not a string, the conversion to a string is done right after while adding the suffix via NumberFormatter.

Comment: Oh sorry indeed, thank you for pointing this out. I will update the answer then,